# mobile backend を用いたプッシュ通知実装について

Tags: javascript, ios, android, monaca

現在、 Monaca を利用したスマホアプリ開発を行っており、プッシュ通知を行いたいのですが
 Google アカウントの設定と mobile backend の準備は完了したので、ソースを書いて実行してみると、必ず以下のエラーが出ます。

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setDeviceToken' of undefined

当然、デバイストークンの取得も登録もできておりません。
ソースは、 Monaca の新規プロジェクトで、「ニフティクラウド mobile backend 用 blank アプリ」を使用し、できた index.html の `script` タグの中を以下のように少し書き換えただけです。

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data:; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ncmb-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
            window.NCMB.monaca.setDeviceToken(
                "xxxxxxxx",
                "xxxxxxxx",
                "xxxxxxxx"
            );
        }, false);
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <p>App template using NIFTY Cloud mobile backend</p>

</body>
</html>
```

調べたところ Cordova のバグである、といった記載も見つかりましたが、対応方法が全くわかりません。
どうすればデバイストークンが取得できるようになりますか？

Comment: こちらを参照してください。[【Monaca】Nifty mBaaSのプッシュ通知を実装する](http://hatopp.wpblog.jp/archives/456)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
ご提示いただきましたサイトを参考に作成してみましたが、残念ながら結果は変わらず、でした。

Comment: プラグインのバージョンを確認しましたか？ver.2でないと正しく動作しません。

Comment: はい。プラグインのバージョンにつきましては念のため「ncmb-push-monaca-plugin」で選択できる
「2.0.0」「2.0.1」「2.0.2」の３つ全てを試した上で、全てダメでした・・・。
終始、setHandlerやsetDeviceTokenは呼べないとエラーが出ます・・・。

Comment: Monacaデバッガー上で作業を行っていますか？デバッガー上ではプラグインが動作しないため確認はできません。

Comment: あああ、わかりました・・・、そういうことですか・・・。
monacaの、デバッグ>デバッガーの説明とインスト－ル>ビルドしてインストール、でAndroidデバッガーをビルドしてインストール。
そこから試すか、通常のビルド後に実機にインストールした環境なら普通にできました。ソースじゃなくて環境の問題でした・・・。お手数をおかけして申し訳ございません。ありがとうございました。